# I use TCP Client to build the connection, and it displayed "socket connected", but 'data=conn.recv' is wrong

Tags: python, tcp

I was trying to establish a connecton between TCP Client and W5500.

there are my codes.

```
socket.set_interface(eth)
server = socket.socket()  # Allocate socket for the server
server_ip = None  # IP address of server
server_port = 50007  # Port to listen on
server.bind((server_ip, server_port))  # Bind to IP and Port
server.listen()  # Begin listening for incoming clients

conn, addr = server.accept()  # Wait for a connection from a client.
print("socket connected")
while True:
eth.maintain_dhcp_lease()

    led.value = not led.value
    time.sleep(1)
    with conn:
        # data = conn.recv()
        # print(data)
        # conn.send(data)  # Echo message back to client
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(10)
            if data:
                print(data)
                conn.send(data)  # Echo message back to client
                break
```

I was trying to build the connection from TCP Client app. Though I have established the connection, just like 'socket connected' in this image, something is wrong with data = conn.recv(10). How to solve it? It's wrong with my net?

conn.send() is ok. But I found if conn.recv() runs, the following will happen.

```
Wiznet5k SimpleServer Test (no DHCP)
Ethernet link is down…
Chip Version: w5500
MAC Address: ['0xde', '0xad', '0xbe', '0xef', '0xfe', '0xed']
My IP address is: 192.168.1.8
*** Get socket.
Reserved sockets: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
Allocated socket # 1.
* Listening on port=50007, ip=192.168.1.8
*** Opening socket 1
* Opening W5k Socket, protocol=33
*** Get socket.
Allocated socket # 0
Dest is (192.168.1.11, 46396), Next listen socknum is #0
*** Get socket.
Reserved sockets: [True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
Allocated socket # 2.
* Listening on port=50007, ip=192.168.1.8
*** Opening socket 2
* Opening W5k Socket, protocol=33
socket connected
socket_available called on socket 1, protocol 33
*** Disconnecting socket 1
*** Closing socket 1
  Waiting for socket to close…
  Socket has closed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 78, in <module>
  File "adafruit_wiznet5k/adafruit_wiznet5k_socket.py", line 276, in wrapper
  File "adafruit_wiznet5k/adafruit_wiznet5k_socket.py", line 499, in recv
  File "adafruit_wiznet5k/adafruit_wiznet5k_socket.py", line 276, in wrapper
  File "adafruit_wiznet5k/adafruit_wiznet5k_socket.py", line 598, in recv_into
TypeError: unsupported types for __gt__: 'NoneType', 'int'
```

I didn't send information at all, it will automatically disconnect like this.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time to publish a post. And I have revised it.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem.
You need to add `conn.settimeout()` before you run `conn.recv()`.

Comment: Please explain *why* this is required. Mere assertion is not enough.